# Rewrite the results of query to time

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have the following code:

```
={"HOURS"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B86:B145,
{REGEXEXTRACT(""&'Sheet1'!D6:D, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B86:B145)), 'Sheet1'!H6:H}, 2, 0)))}
```

This will return (some examples):

```
1h

1h 52s

2h 48m

3m 9s

5m

36s
```

so there are different results (the way it's formatted from Sheet1) h=hour, m=minutes, s=seconds

Is is possible to convert it to a time by editing my formula?

```
01:00:00

01:00:52

02:48:00

00:03:09

00:05:00

00:00:36
```

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c3HdMq4PA50pYr88JqPoG51jvru8ipp8ebe4z5DczTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have edited my answer with a more complete solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"HOURS"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(B86:B, Sheet1!D:H, 5, 0)="-", "-", TEXT(TIME(
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(B86:B, Sheet1!D:H, 5, 0), "(\d+)h")), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(B86:B, Sheet1!D:H, 5, 0), "(\d+)m")), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(B86:B, Sheet1!D:H, 5, 0), "(\d+)s"))), "hh:mm:ss"))))}
```

[image]

---

if those hours are durations use: `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Hi player0! Thanks for your answer. This is definitely what I'm looking for. I'm translating this to the original file and not getting the same result. Would you mind giving a little explanation so I could understand what's happening on the formula? Also, any idea why it doesn't add the total duration in **F147**? Thanks!

Comment: for total you can use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IFERROR(1*F86:F146)), "[hh]:mm:ss"))` see your sheet

Comment: Thanks again! I got the formula working in the original file now. I just don't know what happened (why it worked) maybe I'll research more cuz I still don't understand it haha. Also, the total duration works as intended using your formula. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `=TIME()` function to convert values into a time. For example:

`=TIME(13, 0, 52)` would result in `1:00:52 PM`. You can change the time format in the Format > Number settings if you don't want to include AM/PM, or want the leading 0 in the hour.

[image: time]

If you include a link to your spreadsheet, it would be easier to combine with the formula you already have to find a full solution.

---

**Note:** I may be completely overcomplicating this, but I got this method to work so I'm going to share my solution. I did attempt to combine most of these formulas with no luck.

Im going to go through how to set this up step by step to try to make this as easy as possible.

1. In `Sheet1`, place the formula `=arrayformula(split(H6:H65, " "))` in cell `I6`.
2. In `Sheet1`, place the formula ``` =arrayformula(SPLIT(lower(I6:I65),"qwertyuihmsopadfgjklzxcvbn``-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()")) ``` in cell `K6`.
3. In `Sheet1`, place the formula ``` =iferror(arrayformula(SPLIT(lower(J6:J65),"qwertyuihmsopadfgjklzxcvbn``-=[]\;',./!@#$%^&*()")),"-") ``` in cell `L6`.
4. In `Sheet1`, place the following formula in cell `M6`.

```
=arrayformula(time(
if(iferror(search("h", I6:I65))>1, K6:K65, 0), 
if(iferror(search("h", I6:I65))>1, if(iferror(search("m", J6:J65))>1, L6:L65, 0),if(iferror(search("m", I6:I65))>1, K6:K65, 0)),
if(iferror(search("h", I6:I65))>1, if(iferror(search("m", J6:J65))>1, 0, if(iferror(search("s", J6:J65))>1, L6:L65, 0)), if(iferror(search("s", I6:I65))>1, K6:K65, if(iferror(search("s", J6:J65))>1, L6:L65, 0)))))
```

5. In `MAIN`, place the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(vlookup(B86:B145, Sheet1!D6:M65, 10))` in cell `E86`.
6. In `MAIN`, highlight the range with your time values (`E6:E145`) and go to Format > Number > More Formats > More date and time formats
7. Scroll down until you find `13:30:30`. If you cannot find this in the list, reference the picture below to set the format manually.

[image: time format]

Your times should now be formatted correctly. For aesthetic purposes, the columns in `Sheet1` containing the intermediate formulas can be hidden if needed.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rU9mPKajJfZmk3bShgJ8WUlAGHwzDg2oF-v28JGvtnw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The problem is that the value from the source are in different structures like the examples i have above. Here are some more: 2h 48m,
47m 29s,
2h 45m,
58m 59s,
1h 54m,
59m 34s,
1h 47m,
2h 37s,
1h 47s,
1h 51m,
1h 59m,
2h 57m,

Comment: Would you be able to share a view-only link to your sheet so I have a better understanding as to how to fix it?